# SQS, Lambda & SES param undefined

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sqs

I had this stack setup and working perfectly before, however, all of a sudden I am seeing a strange error in my CloudWatch.

This is my function (Python) for posting a message to SQS (which triggers a lambda function to send an email with SES):

```
def post_email(data, creatingUser=None):
    sqs = boto3.client("sqs", region_name=settings.AWS_REGION)
    # Send message to SQS queue
    response = sqs.send_message(
        QueueUrl=settings.QUEUE_EMAIL,
        DelaySeconds=10,
        MessageAttributes={
            "ToAddress": {"DataType": "String", "StringValue": data.get("ToAddress")},
            "Subject": {"DataType": "String", "StringValue": data.get("Subject")},
            "Source": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": data.get("Source", "ANS <noreply@ansfire.net"),
            },
        },
        MessageBody=(data.get("BodyText"))
        # When SQS pulls this message off, need to ensure that the email was
        #   actually delivered, if so create a notification
    )
```

I print the params out and it is setting the above attributes correctly, however when I look in my CloudWatch this is the message:

```
2020-02-03T20:41:59.847Z    f483293f-e48b-56e5-bb85-7f8d6341c0bf    INFO    {
  Destination: { ToAddresses: [ undefined ] },
  Message: {
    Body: { Text: [Object] },
    Subject: { Charset: 'UTF-8', Data: undefined }
  },
  Source: undefined
}
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error, I needed to get the attributes from the data dictionary prior to calling the send_message function.